# How do I remove Wine program entries from the menu?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I had installed some programms with Wine, but I removed Wine from my computer. Now when I browse all applications in the Unity menu, the symbols of the programms I installed with Wine are still there.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 29):

It should be enough to remove the local wine folder `~/.local/share/applications/wine`.

Comment: Careful doing this as you may have other shortcuts in this folder that you don't want to delete. Better to `rm ~/.local/share/applications/wine-*`.

Comment: ^ has been resolved by editing the post contents

Answer (score 8):

**Carefull - mistakes when using sudo to delete stuff can be disastrous!**

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/wine*.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/wine*.desktop
```

You might need to log out and back in to see the changes, depending on the desktop you are using (kde, gnome, ...)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `alacarte` in order to enable/disable applications using GUI.

[image]

Also you can directly remove the wine .desktop files on `/home/user/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: This is a cleaner solution and while i did clear out the wine related files (hidden files shown), this actually did it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

To remove these leftover menu entries, carefully paste the following commands into a terminal:

```
rm -f ~/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f ~/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm -f ~/.local/share/icons/????_*.{xpm,png}
rm -f ~/.local/share/icons/*-x-wine-*.{xpm,png} }}}
```

Source: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Uninstalling

I posted it here as other answers weren't enough for me. Also I didn't use the last two commands as I didn't find such icon names manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to the Wine programs directory and delete files, then use [Bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net) (a CCleaner-like application) to clean broken links an so on.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Main Menu, scroll to where the left over entries for Wine programs are, now de-select them and then for each one click delete.