# Where is the folder that contains contents of the Applications overview?

Tags: icons

I might've messed some stuff up and I have icons which lead to a non-existent path in the "Show Applications", I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS if that helps.

More specifically I tried running Steam through wine, didn't work but made an icon in the "Show Applications" menu. Even when the path is correct it says it's wrong.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and clarify what went wrong. Exactly what did you do? Add screenshot(s) if needed.

Comment: I think I know what you mean; if you try to locate the files with names ending in “.desktop” you’ll probably find what you’re looking for.  (If you do, be sure to post an answer to your own question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove Wine program entries from the menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37320/how-do-i-remove-wine-program-entries-from-the-menu) tl;dr look for the associated `.desktop` file in the `~/.local/share/applications/` folder.